# How to parse large text file with Apache Tika 1.5?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, apache-tika

**Problem:**
For my test, I want to extract text data from a 335 MB text file which is wikipedia's "pagecounts-20140701-060000.txt" with Apache Tika.

**My solution:**
I tried to use `TikaInputStream` since it provides buffering, then I tried to use `BufferedInputStream`, but that didn't solve my problem. Here is the my test class below:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Printer {
    public void readMyFile(String fname) throws IOException, SAXException,
            TikaException {
        System.out.println("Working...");

        File f = new File(fname);
        // InputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(new File(fname));
        InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));

        Metadata meta = new Metadata();
        ContentHandler content = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

        String mime = new Tika().detect(f);
        meta.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mime);

        System.out.println("trying to parse...");
        try {
            parser.parse(stream, content, meta, new ParseContext());
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer p = new Printer();
        try {
            p.readMyFile("test/pagecounts-20140701-060000.txt");
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
Upon invoking the `parse` method of the `parser` I am getting:

```
Working...
trying to parse...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:535)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:322)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ToTextContentHandler.characters(ToTextContentHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.WriteOutContentHandler.characters(WriteOutContentHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.MatchingContentHandler.characters(MatchingContentHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SecureContentHandler.characters(SecureContentHandler.java:270)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.access$001(SafeContentHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler$1.write(SafeContentHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.filter(SafeContentHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.characters(SafeContentHandler.java:287)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.characters(XHTMLContentHandler.java:278)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser.parse(TXTParser.java:88)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    at com.tastyminerals.cli.Printer.readMyFile(Printer.java:37)
    at com.tastyminerals.cli.Printer.main(Printer.java:46)
```

I tried to increase jre memory consumption up to -Xms512M -Xmx1024M, that didn't work and I don't want to use any bigger values.

**Questions:**
What is wrong with my code?
How should I modify my class to make it extract text from a test file >300 MB with Apache Tika?

Comment: Would you add more of the OutOfMemoryError stack trace? Then we could see where it lifts off.

Comment: Using BodyContentHandler probably isn't very smart, as that buffers the whole content into memory before returning. Can you try swapping that for a ContentHandler which processes the output text data as you go without buffering?

Comment: If I use `ContentHandler content = new LinkContentHandler();` the `OutOfMemoryError` does not appear. Guess you are right, I just don't have enough memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set like this to avoid the limit in size :-

```
BodyContentHandler bodyHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use incremental parsing

```java
Tika tika = new Tika();
Reader fulltext = null; 
String contentStr = null;
try {                   
    fulltext = tika.parse(response.getEntityInputStream());
    contentStr = IOUtils.toString(fulltext);
} finally {
    fulltext.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pass BodyContentHandler a Writer or OutputStream instead of int

As Gagravarr mentioned, the `BodyContentHandler` you've used is building an internal string buffer of the file's content. Because Tika is trying to store the entire content in memory at once, this approach will hit `OutOfMemoryError` exception for large files.

**If your goal is to write out the Tika parse results to another file for later processing**, you can construct `BodyContentHandler` with a `Writer` (or `OutputStream` directly) instead of passing an `int`:

```
Path outputFile = Path.of("output.txt"); // Paths.get() if not using Java 11
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(Files.newOutputStream(outputFile));
BodyContentHandler content = new BodyContentHandler(printWriter);
```

And then call Tika parse:

```
Path inputFile = Path.of("input.txt");
TikaInputStream inputStream = TikaInputStream.get(inputFile);

AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata meta = new Metadata();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

parser.parse(inputStream, content, meta, context);
```

By doing this, Tika will automatically write the content to the outputFile as it parses, instead of trying to keep it all in memory. [Using a PrintWriter will buffer the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177690/is-printwriter-buffered), reducing the number of writes to disk.

Note that Tika will **not** automatically close your input or output streams for you.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution with ByteArrayInputStream

I had a similar problem with CSV files. If they were read in Java with the wrong charset, only a part of the records could be imported. The method from my library assigns the correct encoding to the file and prevents reading errors.

```
public static String lib_getCharset( String fullFile ) {

    // Initialize variables.    
    String             returnValue = ""; 
    BodyContentHandler handler     = new BodyContentHandler( -1 );
    Metadata           meta        = new Metadata();

    // Convert the BufferedInputStream to a ByteArrayInputStream.
    try( final InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( fullFile ) ) ) {

        InputStream  bais    = new ByteArrayInputStream( is.readAllBytes() );
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        TXTParser    parser  = new TXTParser();
    
        // Run the Tika TXTParser and read the metadata.          
        try {
    
            parser.parse( bais, handler, meta, context );
    
            // Fill the  metadata's names in an array ... 
            String[] metaNames = meta.names();
    
            // ... and iterate over it.
            for( String metaName : metaNames ) {
        
                // Check if a charset is described.
                if( metaName.equals( "Content-Encoding" ) ) {

                    returnValue =  meta.get( metaName );
                }
            }            

        } catch( SAXException | TikaException se_te ) {
        
            se_te.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch( IOException e ) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

    return returnValue;
}
```

Using scanner, the file can then be imported as follows.

```
Scanner scanner     = null;
String  charsetChar = TrnsLib.lib_getCharset( fullFileName );
    
try {

    // Scan the file, e.g. with UTF-8 or
    //                          ISO8859-1 or windows-1252 for ANSI.
    scanner = new Scanner( new File( fullFileName ), charsetChar );
        
} catch( FileNotFoundException e ) {
    
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't forget the assignment of the two dependencies in the POM.XML:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-core/2.4.1/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-parser-text-module/2.4.1/

and the definition of the requires in module-info.java:

```
module org.wnt.wnt94lib {
    requires transitive org.apache.tika.core;
    requires transitive org.apache.tika.parser.txt;
}
```

My solution works fine with small files (up to about 100 lines of 300 characters). Larger files need more attention. The Babylonian confusion around `CR` and `LF` led to inconsistencies under *Apache Tika*. If the parameter is set to `-1`, the whole text file is read for `BodyContentHandler`, but only the above-mentioned 100 lines are used to find the correct charset. And especially in CSV files, exotic characters like ä, ö or ü are rare. But, out of luck, *Apache* finds the combined characters `CR` and `LF` and concludes that it must be an ANSI  instead of a UTF-8 file.

So, what can you do? - Quick and dirty, you can add the letters `- ÄÖÜ` to the file's first line. – However, the following solution is better: Load the file with *Notepad++*. Show all characters under *View*, *Show Symbol*. Under *Search*, *Replace...* delete all `CR`. To do this, activate the selection *Extended* under *Search Mode* and enter the characters `\r\n` under *Find what* and `\n` under *Replace with*. Set the cursor on the file's first line and press the button *Replace All*. It frees the file from the burden of remembering the good old typewriter and converts it into a proper Unix file with UTF-8.

Afterwards, however, do not edit the CSV file with Excel. The programme, which I otherwise really appreciate, converts your file back into one with `CR`-ballast. For correct saving, without `CR`, you have to use VBA. *Ekkehard Horner* describes how at: [VBA : save a file with UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435662/vba-save-a-file-with-utf-8-without-bom)