# Visio: DOS Sharing violation (Error 1532)

Tags: vba, windows, ms-office, visio

So I'm really confused right now. Out of the blue my code gets me the error "DOS Sharing violation".

[image: Image with the Error]

It's weird because, it says that is trying to save my document, but I just want to open it.

This is my Code:

```
Public Sub ReadActivity()
Dim vsoDocument As Visio.Document
Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page


Set vsoDocument = Documents.Open("C:\Users\Philip\Dropbox\Test\Aktivität0.vsdx")
Set vsoPage = vsoDocument.Pages(1)

SvgExport (ActiveDocument.path & "\files_and_images\" & Left(ActiveDocument.name, (InStrRev(ActiveDocument.name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) & ".svg") 
CreateCodeActivity

vsoDocument.Close
End Sub
```

So as you might see the code is simple nothing special is going on. 
Before calling the method I'm using this for encoding my textfile: [VBA : save a file with UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435662/vba-save-a-file-with-utf-8-without-bom)

And two things are very weird. First of all, I used this method two days in a row for coding the method "CreateCodeActivity" and I didn't have any problems. And second, if I call the method let's say three times, on the third time everything works perfectly...

Where might be the problem?

Comment: Do you use Kaspersky AntiVir? https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?s=2932812927f84277db86e585f190a644&showtopic=360718&pid=2646952&st=0&#entry2646952

Comment: No, but good point. Maybe it's the windows defense program... I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Shmukko for the tip, it is really the windows defender that gives me the error.

For Windows 10 the solution  is: Go to Settings and select Update & security  -> Windows Defender. Select Exclude a file extension and enter the file type for Visio.

That's it.