# Save TXT file as UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: excel, vba

Everything works but, the code creates an txt file in UTF-8 with BOM, I would like to create a txt with UTF-8, but without BOM.

How can I do this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveWorkSheetAsCSV()
    
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Test"
    
    Dim FileName As String: FileName = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hh.mm ") & " Test file"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Copy
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dwb.SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & FileName & ".txt", xlCSVUTF8, Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FolderPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA : save a file with UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435662/vba-save-a-file-with-utf-8-without-bom)

Comment: Atm not really, I saw that post, but I don't understand how I should integrate that part inside of my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the BOM, read the file into an ADODB Stream Object, move the position by 3 bytes and then using another stream save the bytes to a new file.

```vb
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False 
    Call RemoveBOM(FolderPath, filename) ' add this line to your code
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FolderPath
```

Add this sub

```vb
Sub RemoveBOM(FolderPath As String, filename As String)

    Dim objStreamUTF8, objStreamUTF8NoBOm
    Set objStreamUTF8 = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set objStreamUTF8NoBOm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
    With objStreamUTF8
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile FolderPath & "\" & filename & ".txt"
        .Type = 2 'adTypeText
        .Position = 3
    End With

    With objStreamUTF8NoBOm
       .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
       .Open
       objStreamUTF8.CopyTo objStreamUTF8NoBOm
       .SaveToFile FolderPath & "\" & filename & "_noBOM.txt", 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
    End With

    objStreamUTF8.Close
    objStreamUTF8NoBOm.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Im going to try this right now!

Comment: I keep getting an error that it can't open the file? Could you mabye show/help me how to merge this code above inside my existing code?

Comment: @Ulquiorra Which file can't it open ?

Comment: @CPD1802 I have added the first part in my code and created another sub for the second part. When I run it, it says it cant open the file?

Comment: @ulqui You only added the one line to your code, yes ?

Comment: Aaaah wait I think I know where it went wrong give me a sec!

Comment: So when I do this I get 3 errors, for the `adTypeText and adTypeBinary and adSaveCreateOverWrite` The error I get is that these variables are not defined.

Comment: @Ulqui OK, I had updated my code with the numbers for those constants.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I should told you I tried that also according to this info: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_stream_type.asp. So with the constants added I'm getting the error that the file could not be opened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231387/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-ulquiorra-schiffer).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help it works perfect!