# Save a CSV as UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: excel, vba, csv, utf-8

I have hundreds of CSV files containing text in Japanese.
When I open them in Excel, the characters look garbled.
And when I open them with Notepad, the characters look fine.
I got my computer's locale changed to Japan, but the problem did not get resolved.

However, when I manually open the files in Notepad,
save them with the character encoding UTF-8 without BOM,
and then open the files in Excel, the characters look as they should.
I have also recorded a macro with Notepad++ for this, but it cannot be used with VBA as per my knowledge. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I want to automate this process with Excel macro.
I tried searching the code on the Internet, but did not get any solution.

Unfortunately, there is no way to attach the file.
But, can someone please give a macro to:
Open a .csv file in Excel with the character encoding `UTF-8 without BOM`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA : save a file with UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435662/vba-save-a-file-with-utf-8-without-bom)

Comment: I tried to run the code after changing the file path\name against .SaveToFile, but it did not work...
Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: "it did not work" tells people exactly nothing. Does it error?

Comment: Just to clarify, but normally Excel defaults to opening CSV files in the default Windows locale encoding, which if the file is actually UTF-8 without BOM looks garbled.  Excel normally needs UTF8 **with** BOM to use UTF-8.  This seems backward.

Comment: Hi @braX
Sorry for making it unclear...
There is no error and I don't see the timestamp changing, which means the file is not getting saved... Nothing seems to be happening to the user's eye, although something could actually be happening in the background.

Comment: Hi @MarkTolonen
Thanks for the information. I tried saving them with different enumerations given on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoencoding), but that too did not make the characters normal...

Comment: What encoding does Notepad++ show when you first open the file. ? Does the filesize decrease by 3 bytes when you save without BOM .