# Is PrintWriter buffered?

Tags: java, file-io, java-io, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I know that the `PrintWriter` is really good if we want to write formatted data, and I also know the use of `BufferedWriter` to improve IO performance.

But I tried something like this,

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
pw.println("Statement 1");
pw.println("Statement 2");
//pw.flush();
```

I observed that when the flush method is commented there is no output, but when I uncomment it, I get the desired output.

**This is only possible if the PrintWriter is buffered.** If so, then what is the point of wrapping a PrintWriter using a BufferedWriter and then writing it?

**Though the javadoc doesn't mention anywhere that the PrintWriter is buffered**, but it seems so.

Comment: all the writers have flush method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I checked JDK versions starting with 1.6.0_45 and all of them have [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-boolean-) constructor present:

```
/**
 * Creates a new PrintWriter from an existing OutputStream.  This
 * convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate
 * OutputStreamWriter, which will convert characters into bytes using the
 * default character encoding.
 *
 * @param  out        An output stream
 * @param  autoFlush  A boolean; if true, the <tt>println</tt>,
 *                    <tt>printf</tt>, or <tt>format</tt> methods will
 *                    flush the output buffer
 *
 * @see java.io.OutputStreamWriter#OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream)
 */
public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)), autoFlush);
```

Hence PrintWritter uses buffered output. If you would like to use the code you pointed out, you can create the PrintWriter with the **autoflush** set to **true**, that will ensure that using one of the [println](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println--), [printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) or [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) methods would flush the stream. So, your code would look like this in the given context:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
pw.println("Statement 1");
pw.println("Statement 2");
```

Comment: Well, just want to point out that if it isn't mentioned anywhere in the Java specs that `PrintWriter` should use buffers, this might not remain so in the future Java versions. Implementations can change. I am pretty sure that this is called Abstraction or Encapsulation - not sure which though.

Comment: @JohnRed thank you for your comment, if you think the response can be improved, please edit it.

Answer (score 8):

From the Java 8 source for PrintWriter

```
/**
 * Creates a new PrintWriter from an existing OutputStream.  This
 * convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate
 * OutputStreamWriter, which will convert characters into bytes using the
 * default character encoding.
 *
 * @param  out        An output stream
 * @param  autoFlush  A boolean; if true, the <tt>println</tt>,
 *                    <tt>printf</tt>, or <tt>format</tt> methods will
 *                    flush the output buffer
 *
 * @see java.io.OutputStreamWriter#OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream)
 */
public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
    this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)), autoFlush);
```

You can see that PrintWriter uses BufferedWriter and that it has an option `autoFlush` which would only make sense if it was buffered.

Answer (score 2):

`PrintWriter` is buffered. The difference is that `PrintWriter` offers convenience methods for writing formatted string representations of objects like `println()` and `printf()`. It also has auto-flushing (so obviously it has a buffer).

Both classes are efficient. If you enable `PrintWriter`'s auto flushing, then it may be less so (because it will flush every time you call something like `println()`). Another difference is that `PrintWriter` doesn't really let you write bytes directly.

Comment: PrintWriter too has write methods. "Another difference is that PrintWriter doesn't really let you write bytes directly" : I don't understand this statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think that since PrintWriter too can read the String at once, it would be using the buffer.